# Could not seralize gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPDialog

Tags: sip, jain-sip

I'm trying to seralize out `gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPDialog` but it can't be done. can someone help me in fixing the bug in it?

Since the InnerClass  '`AckSendingStrategyImpl`' does not implement serializable, the entire `SipDialog` is not serializable. This is a blocker defect.

I need either '`AckSendingStrategyImpl`' be serializable or the member '`ackSendingStrategy`' be tran

Can someone help in overcoming this situation?

Comment: please mention your sample code and explain your question briefly.

Comment: While serailzing an object of SIPDialog, I get  java.io.NotSerializableException: gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPDialog$AckSendingStrategyImpl.                    static String toString( Serializable o ){
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
            oos.writeObject( o );
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: That's a bug. You should open an issue here https://java.net/jira/browse/JSIP and I will take a look at it. You can try to mark the field transient and it may be sufficient for your needs. If you need fully working replicated dialog things get more complicated and you must consider the tradeoffs.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a new Jira - https://java.net/jira/browse/JSIP-485.   Please have a look at it.

Comment: I can't move forward without fixing this defect. Thanks for the effort.